# Website gallery of pictures loading slowly and overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, file-upload

I have posted about this issue im having before, but my code has changed since then. When I load a "projects" page of my website, there's supposed to be a gallery of "cards" with pictures that loads into a grid like in the picture below:
[Website with the pictures replaced with stock images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SN32.png)
When I load the website after clearing the cache this is what it looks like:
[Website with screwed up cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOS1V.png)
My first step in improving this was to lower the resolution of all the images, so now they're 320p. This helped a bit but not too much. Then I found a post about preloading images, so now I do that when the home page of my website loads, but this doesn't help when someone goes to the projects page first. That preloading code is below:

```
<div class="hidden">
        <script type="text/javascript">
                var images = new Array()
                function preload() {
                    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                        images[i] = new Image()
                        images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
                    }
                }
                preload(
                    "../assets/CNC Front Full Render 320p.png",
                    "../assets/DIODE Board Full Render 320p.png",
                    "../assets/Dock Trailer Full Render 320p.png",
                    "../assets/Fold3r Full Render 320p.png",
                    "../assets/Car Full Views 320p.png",
                    "../assets/Stator Full Render 320p.png",
                    "../assets/Ventilator Full Render 320p.png",
                    "../assets/F4 Robot Full Render 320p.png",
                    "../assets/2020 FRC Robot Render 320p.png",
                    "../assets/2019 FRC Robot Render 320p.png",
                    "../assets/2018 FRC Robot Render 320p.png",
                    "../assets/2017 FRC Robot Render 320p.png",
                    "../assets/Autonoprint Render 320p",
                    "../assets/Website.png"
                )
        </script>
    </div>
```

Another thing I did was specified how big each picture is in each project picture html's styling, that code is below:

```
<img src="../assets/Picture 320p.png" width=100% height=66.6%>
```

I don't know where to go from here, any help is appreciated. I know little to no JS so please explain things clearly.
Thanks in advance,
Clayton

Answer (score 0):

my answer may help a little with loading images faster on a site although it may not necessarily solve your issue completely. Have you tried compressing images using something like tinypng.com? Basically it reduces the file size of your images without loss of quality (for the most part).